# Let n be a positive integer. If a, b, c real numbers such that a <c ^ n <b. Let number δ> 0 such that a<(c + r) ^ n <b for all r such that | r | <δ.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $a$ , $b$, $c$ real numbers such that $a<\ c^n<\ b$ . Then there exist a number $ δ>0 $ such that $a<\ (c+r)^n<\ b$ for all $r$ such that $|r|<\ δ$ .

Note: Do not use continuous functions.

Comment: I tried to make this question, but I'm no idea, tried for sequences but was not getting good. Someone knows how to do this question?

Comment: By induction using the concept and the results of the nth root of a real number is unique and nonnegative. Anyone have any idea how to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $n$ is odd. Then the function $x^n$ is monotone (monotone functions are allowed, I  guess?) and the inequality is equivalent to
$$
 a^{1/n}<c+r<b^{1/n}
$$
so it suffices to take $\delta=\min\{b^{1/n}-c,c-a^{1/n}\}$.
For even $n$: exercise (consider several cases: $a>0$, $a\le0$ etc.).

Comment: Very thanks!! :)